# Separate drawable folder for fetching images

Tags: android, android-studio

I currently use this method:

```
activity.getResources().getIdentifier("pr" + Integer.toString(img_id), "drawable", activity.getPackageName()))
```

to get some images from the drawable folder.
The problem is that I want to have a separate folder for images and to be able to use the same method but for example using profile_icons instead of drawable.

I tried creating a new Android Resource Directory with this name and it doesnt see the images.

Is there a method to create a separate folder which is seen by getResources().getIdentifier ?

Thanks

Comment: you can add seperate folder to Asset and add that your images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a method to create a separate folder which is seen by getResources().getIdentifier ?

No, sorry. As the one comment suggests, use `assets/` for this. Or, stick with your current prefix-based system (if I understand your code correctly).